# Finding out where TypeErrors are thrown

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, amf, typeerror

I am having a problem that is driving me nuts.
Recently I configured my BlazeDS to use Array instead of ArrayCollection for performance reasons. Additionally I adjusted my templates to generate Array properties.

Everything wen't fine. All except one function that causes TypeError: Error #1034. These are being thrown before the result callback is called. It claims to have problems casting an ArrayCollection to Array. I removed the generated types to make Flex use Objects instead, but these did not contain any ArrayCollections. My question now is: How can I get the stack-traces of errors thrown in event-handlers?

I allready added handlers for unhandledExceptions in all of my modules and they are called if errors occur in code triggered from user-interaction, but they don't seem to be able to catch stuff thrown by event-handlers.

How can I track these Errors?

Chris

PS: The classes are:
    package de.upw.ps.ucg.model.ucg.scheduler {

```
[Bindable]
[RemoteClass(alias="de.upw.ps.ucg.model.ucg.scheduler.Task")]
public class Task extends TaskBase {
}
}
```

And:

```
package de.upw.ps.ucg.model.ucg.scheduler {

import de.upw.ps.ucg.model.oval.common.OvalVersionedIdentifier;
import flash.utils.IExternalizable;

[Bindable]
public class TaskBase {

public function TaskBase() {}


    private var _aborted:Boolean;
    private var _characteristicsId:String;
    private var _currentExecutorPhase:JobExecutorPhase;
    private var _definitionSetName:String;
    private var _definitionSetVid:OvalVersionedIdentifier;
    private var _endTime:Date;
    private var _enqueueTime:Date;
    private var _environmentId:String;
    private var _environmentName:String;
    private var _messages:Array;
    private var _numberOfDefinitions:int;
    private var _processedNumberOfTests:int;
    private var _resultsId:String;
    private var _schedulerJob:SchedulerJob;
    private var _startTime:Date;
    private var _statusMessage:String;
    private var _taskId:String;
    private var _totalNumberOfTests:int;

    public function set aborted(value:Boolean):void {
        _aborted = value;
    }
    public function get aborted():Boolean {
        return _aborted;
    }

    public function set characteristicsId(value:String):void {
        _characteristicsId = value;
    }
    public function get characteristicsId():String {
        return _characteristicsId;
    }

    public function set currentExecutorPhase(value:JobExecutorPhase):void {
        _currentExecutorPhase = value;
    }
    public function get currentExecutorPhase():JobExecutorPhase {
        return _currentExecutorPhase;
    }

    public function set definitionSetName(value:String):void {
        _definitionSetName = value;
    }
    public function get definitionSetName():String {
        return _definitionSetName;
    }

    public function set definitionSetVid(value:OvalVersionedIdentifier):void {
        _definitionSetVid = value;
    }
    public function get definitionSetVid():OvalVersionedIdentifier {
        return _definitionSetVid;
    }

    public function set endTime(value:Date):void {
        _endTime = value;
    }
    public function get endTime():Date {
        return _endTime;
    }

    public function set enqueueTime(value:Date):void {
        _enqueueTime = value;
    }
    public function get enqueueTime():Date {
        return _enqueueTime;
    }

    public function set environmentId(value:String):void {
        _environmentId = value;
    }
    public function get environmentId():String {
        return _environmentId;
    }

    public function set environmentName(value:String):void {
        _environmentName = value;
    }
    public function get environmentName():String {
        return _environmentName;
    }

    public function set messages(value:Array):void {
        _messages = value;
    }
    public function get messages():Array {
        return _messages;
    }

    public function set numberOfDefinitions(value:int):void {
        _numberOfDefinitions = value;
    }
    public function get numberOfDefinitions():int {
        return _numberOfDefinitions;
    }

    public function set processedNumberOfTests(value:int):void {
        _processedNumberOfTests = value;
    }
    public function get processedNumberOfTests():int {
        return _processedNumberOfTests;
    }

    public function set resultsId(value:String):void {
        _resultsId = value;
    }
    public function get resultsId():String {
        return _resultsId;
    }

    public function set schedulerJob(value:SchedulerJob):void {
        _schedulerJob = value;
    }
    public function get schedulerJob():SchedulerJob {
        return _schedulerJob;
    }

    public function set startTime(value:Date):void {
        _startTime = value;
    }
    public function get startTime():Date {
        return _startTime;
    }

    public function set statusMessage(value:String):void {
        _statusMessage = value;
    }
    public function get statusMessage():String {
        return _statusMessage;
    }

    public function set taskId(value:String):void {
        _taskId = value;
    }
    public function get taskId():String {
        return _taskId;
    }

    public function set totalNumberOfTests(value:int):void {
        _totalNumberOfTests = value;
    }
    public function get totalNumberOfTests():int {
        return _totalNumberOfTests;
    }
}
}
```

Both classes are generated by my maven build from a corresponding Java Class and the Types do fit together nicely.

Comment: Not sure I understand.  You just said they're throwing errors...

Comment: The problem is that I am getting these Errors before the first callback is executed, so I guess it has to do with a problem in Deserialization of the data sent back from the server. I checked, the response does not contain an ArrayCollection (and therefore it should not be albe to throw such an error). My problem is that usually the Debugger suspends in such cases and I can see where the problem is. In this case it does not suspend and a simple trace message is output without a stacktrace. Therefore I have no idea WHERE something is going wrong.

Comment: You're right, it should be during the deserialization.  Do you have any RemoteClass metadata that ties an as3 class to a java DTO? You should try to show more code.

Comment: I added the classes I am using. As an addition ... I am actually getting those errors even I am using the default "Object" class for deserialization (This is really spooky) ... so my real problem is: How can I see what is going wrong and especially where.

Comment: Are you sure the error is even in deserialization? Maybe it's happening afterward.

Comment: Well I don't have any other callbacks registered for that call and the trace statements are allready output before the first callback is called. So it has to be somewhere between receiving the response from the server and calling the callbacks ... so I guess deserialization it the only thing in-between :-(

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the socket class that's reading in all these messages? Trace out the buffer before the deserialisation and you should at least be able to find the class that's giving you hassle.

Failing that, trace out the object after deserialisation and it should be the very first one after the error is thrown.

Comment: I would do this, but unfortunately I am simply using an ordinary RemotObject communicating using AMF with my BlazeDS Server. I have no Idea how to set a breakpoint in the Socket class for this.

Comment: I just tried to debug the reading of the response ... unfortunatley MessageResponder.result(message) is the bottom of the debugger stack and here the message is allready parsed ... I have no Idea how to debug the higher levels. Looking even deeper into the code, the Socket is propably an Object of type flash.net.NetConnection, but I am unable to view any code for this, as this seems to ba a native Flash Player class.

Comment: I'm using the Socket class as well. I call `readBytes()` into a `ByteArray`, then call `readObject()` on the `ByteAray` to get the object. It's when it calls `readObject()` that the deserialisation happens. Can you get in there before and trace out the `ByteArray`? It'll give you the object.

Comment: You could also try extending the `Socket` class, overriding the `readBytes()` method to trace out what's coming in before calling `super.readBytes()`. The use that in place of the vanilla `Socket`

Comment: As mentioned in the original Question. I would like a way to simply get a stacktrace to where the error is comming from. The result is 100% correctly parsed and the object is 100% the way it should be ... I have absolutely no clue at to where the TypeError is comming from. Your suggestion would make ich nessecarry to re-implement a lof of classes of the flex framework.

Comment: Gah, I checked my code where I found a TypeError and was trying to see where it came from, but in the middle of checking, the error disappeared (even though it had the same data), so I never got to narrow it down. What I guess: It's probably coming from when you're deserialising an object within an object (or an array of objects), and it's trying to access a property before the object is created (it's deserialised in a try..catch which is why you've just a trace). It that case, I assume it either creates it, or waits until it's created. If you can't narrow it down (remove props), just ignore

Comment: If you want a stacktrace by the way, try something like this: http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_How_to_get_stack_trace_anywhere_in_debug_flash_pla-17320.html

Answer (score 0):

This is something you'll have to debug on your own, but I have a gut feeling that the problem is because the data being sent by your java DTO is not the same as your AS3 class, even though that you have the RemoteClass metadata saying that it is.

Are you missing a property? or have a property mismatch? That is the most likely cause of your error.  I suggest you debug the java side as much as you can and use something like firebug to see the request/response of the server.

Comment: These were the fist things I checked. The properties are correct, all properties are correctly filled. And still I am getting a TypeError, even if the result contains none (Remember that I said, even when using no dedicated class and falling back on Flex' deserialization using the class "Object" I am getting these errors). I am not looking for a problem in deserialization, I am looking for a way to debug such errors in general as it seems impossible to see where they are comming from.